# Фактура и текстура: одно и то же?

Tags: значение-слов

Подскажите, пожалуйста, слова "фактура" и "текстура" — синонимы? И если нет, то в чем разница?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Фактура — характер поверхности материала. Визуально-тактильные характеристики. 
Текстура более относится к составляющим элементам материала во всем его объеме. 
Фактура дерева — похоже на дерево на вид и на ощупь. Текстура дерева значит — волокна, характерная для дерева плотность, сучки, кольца...

Answer (score 3):

ТЕКСТУ́РА, ы, мн. нет, ж. [< лат. textura **ткань; строение; связь**, соединение]. тех.**Особенности строения** твердого вещества, обусловленные характером расположения его составных частей.*Т. горных пород.*Тексту́рный —относящийся к текстуре.||Ср. фактура (во 2-м знач.).
Яндекс.Словари › Толковый словарь иноязычных слов. — 2004

ФАКТУ́РА -ы; ж. [от лат. factura - обработка, строение] 1. Характер **обработки**, строение какого-л. материала, определяющие его **внешний вид**. *Гладкая, ворсистая ф. ткани. Интересная ф. дерева. Ф. стекла, гранита. Воспроизвести фактуру мрамора.*
dic.academic.ru › Большой толковый словарь русского языка. - 1-е изд-е: СПб.: Норинт

Теперь из словаря **синонимов**   [здесь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/188200):
Текстура - микротекстура, строение, рисунок, экзоглиф, эндоглиф, ориентация, наслоенность.
Фактура - накладная; выделка, выработка, истина, облик, фигура, правда, своеобразие.

Comment: Фактуру  видим  и  ещё  пальцами  ощущаем,  а  текстуру  только  видим.